# Adaptedness and Independence

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a stochastic process on $\mathbb{R}$ and $W$ a Brownian motion, **independent** of $X$.

If $X$ is deterministic, then $X$ is adapted to the filtration generated by $W$.

Does the converse also hold, i.e., if $X$ is adapted to the filtration generated by $W$, is $X$ necessarily deterministic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  Because $X$ is adapted to the filtration generated by $W$, given any set of paths $A$ we have that $X^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal F^W$, so $X^{-1}(A) = W^{-1}(B)$ for some set $B$.  Thus $$\mathbb{P}(X \in A) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A, W \in B) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A) \mathbb{P}(W \in B) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A)^2.$$  This implies $\mathbb{P}(X \in A) \in \{0,1\}$, i.e. $X$ is deterministic.